Do we need LICQ for SOSC in KKT points?
I am currently reading Numerical Optimization by Wright and Nocedal.
I stumbled upon the second-order necessary and sufficient conditions.
 and 
What confuses me is that LICQ is apparently not needed for the sufficient condition and I am wondering if I understand this part correctly? For me it makes a lot of sense that when you want to go from necessary to sufficient, you need to add stricter constraints (change $\geq$ to $>$), but how come we suddenly do not need LICQ anymore?
Moreover, what does it mean, if LICQ does not hold, but the secon-order sufficient condition? Can this even happen?
